# How to make last line of wrapped text in PDf fully visible

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc, pdfsharpcore

PDFs are created from report template which contains text fields having left, height, width and top properties:

[image]

Paragraph does not have position and size. So text is added to paragraph inside TextFrame. Paragraph contains variable number of lines and has variable height. Page break should inserted if top position + height is greater that printable area in page.

If paragraph is added to textframe and paragraph height is extended to two lines, line in page is only partially visible sometimes.

Example is in
https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/files/12776630/actual.behaviour.pdf

To reproduce run code in MigraDoc template:

```
static Document CreateDocument()
{
    // Create a new MigraDoc document.
    var document = new Document { };
    // Add a section to the document.
    var section = document.AddSection();
    section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0;
    section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0;
    for (int p = 1; p < 100; p++)
    {
        var textFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
        textFrame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
        textFrame.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = Unit.FromCentimeter(0.11);
        textFrame.Height = Unit.FromCentimeter(0.47);
        var paragraph = textFrame.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.Format.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        paragraph.Format.Font.Size = 10;
        paragraph.AddText("Maksekorraldus 123456");
        paragraph.Format.SpaceBefore = 0;
        paragraph.Format.SpaceAfter = 0;
    }
    return document;
}
```

Full VS solution is in https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/files/12776629/texttruncatedinendofpage.zip

How to make all lines fully visible? In real application paragraph height is not known and Migradoc does not provide method to get paragraph height. So textframe height cannot increased by code.

Using  PDFsharp-MigraDoc 6.0.0-preview-3

Comment: It looks like page break should inserted before partial Textframe or before before partial line. How to implement this in application using Migradoc? It is expected that Migradoc break pages in proper places. Migradoc calculates paragraph height in final phase. Paragraph height is not known then code in question creates paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textframes do not break to the next page, this is by design.
Callers must ensure that a textframe fits onto the page.

For normal text, it is recommend to have the text in the body of the section or in a table.
Note that table cells will not break across pages.
Tables will break at cell boundaries.
Paragraphs in the body will break at line boundaries.

Comment: PDFs are created from report template which contains text fields having left, height, width and top properties. Paragraph does not have position and size. So only solution is to add text inside TextFrame. How to force page break if textframe does not fit into page?

Comment: @Andrus Add a `PageBreak` to the section before adding the `TextFrame`.

Comment: Page break adding in user code requires knowing current top position and textframe height after stretching. How to add such page break to the sample code in question?

Comment: @Andrus TextFrames are usually used to place text at absolute positions on a page. When you place them at an absolute position, make sure the width and height also fits.
If you want to have them flow with the body text, consider using a Table or a Paragraph outside a TextFrame. What's the purpose of the TextFrame in your sample code? I do not see a need for a TextFrame here.

Comment: I updated question, added description of the issue and image. TextFrames are used for absolute left position and to create absolute vertial space from previous element using DistanceTop. MigraDoc does not allow such positions for paragraphs.

Comment: @Andrus MigraDoc allows `SpaceBefore` and left indent for paragraphs. And AFAIK MigraDoc breaks "normal" non-floating TextFrames to the next page. So either use non-floating TextFrames that will break to the next page or use regular paragraphs with SpaceBefore and left indent. Or use floating TextFrames and take responsibility for page breaks with PDFsharp/MigraDoc up to version 6.0.

Comment: If textFrame is not used, how to specify paragraph width? Widths are set in report designer by end user and should be exactly the same in PDF. Or how to calculate paragraph height? If paragraph height is known, TextFrame height can set to this value and hopefully non-floating TextFrames are paged correctly.

Comment: @Andrus For `Paragraph` objects you can set left indent and right indent. Thus you set the width of the paragraph indirectly (page width minus page margins minus paragraph indents).

Comment: Can paragraphs with predefined widths positioned in any position in page using SpaceBefore, left and right indent popreties? Will automatic pagination work properly when those properties is used to make gaps between paragraphs? Or is it more reasonable to put paragraph inside TextFrame like in code in question, calculate paragraph height and set TextFrame height to paragraph height for proper pagination?

Comment: @Andrus Paragraphs work very well - including control of automatic pagebreaks. Textframes are the solution if you need text at absolute positions or at relative positions outside the body. Paragraphs are IMHO the way to go for text in the body. Tables in the body can be used for special layouting requirements.